# odbc_exec error with progress

Tags: codeigniter, odbc, openedge

I am using Codeigniter Database Active Record (ODBC Driver). The application run well. But starting this day, there are error when trying to fetch data from Progress database (connected via odbc). The error message:

> Severity: Warning  --> odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error:
>   [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Unexpected
>   Network Error.  ErrNum = 10054, SQL state 08S01 in SQLExecDirect
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wavinet2-permana\system\database\drivers\odbc\odbc_driver.php
>   153

Error is in odbc_exec command. When I try to fetch data without using Codeigniter Active Record, it work. Data fetched. Trying to var_dump($this->db_odbc->conn_id) it return Resource. Network error ? I try to set up LinkedServer on my SQLServer and run the query generated by ActiveRecord, it work, data fetched successfully.

I'm confuse, what is another posibilities that cause the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make  certain that you have started up your database properly. There is a fairly substantial thread that has what sounds like it may be your problem here: http://www.progresstalk.com/showthread.php?116855-102B-ODBC-connection-Problem

Also something else to look at if you are running over SSL:

> Change the data source PacketSize setting. The correct setting is 32.
>
> PacketSize=32
>
> On Windows this will require a registry edit to make this change.

See: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/8500